# User to user payment on stripe

Tags: stripe-payments

My requirement is, from my application I want my user to transfer the amount to another user of my application. Assume that both user have stripe account. I have gone through stripe docs, and I understood that in order to do transfer from one user account to another I need to use **stripe connect**. I could able to do authentication and I'm getting access token successfully for the sender. How can I make a transfer to a recipient ? I have only recipient's email id with me. Should I need to create a recipient through code and do the transfer using that recipient id returns from stripe ? 
Im using php. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Stripe Connect doesn't work like that. Instead, Connect allows an application to make card charges on behalf of a user and take a portion of the amount. The rest is automatically and immediately put into the user's Stripe account, where it's subject to the normal bank account transfer rules (2-7 day rolling transfers or API-driven manual transfers).

Another way to do this is using Stripe Recipients and Transfers. For example, your application charges a customer $10. You create a Recipient for your user using their bank account information (account number and routing number). Then, you can create a Transfer from your Stripe account to their bank account. Note that this only works for US bank accounts as of today.

If you really want to do user to user transfers, unfortunately Stripe isn't the platform for you. You could use PayPal or you could possibly use [Balanced Payments](http://balancedpayments.com/), although again you can only transfer money to and from US bank accounts.